# PHP strtotime doesn't work with string in text file

Tags: php

So I have this line in `.txt` file:

```
<strong>Position Id:</strong> P0001
<strong>Title:</strong> Sale Clerks
<strong>Description:</strong> do something  
<strong>Closing Date:</strong> 25/09/2013   
<strong>Position:</strong> Full-Time    
<strong>Contract:</strong> On-Going 
<strong>Applicated by:</strong> Post
<strong>Location:</strong> NSW
```

I want to compare the closing date in text file with current server date.this is what i have so far and strtotime wouldn't print out anything.

*`P.S:`* I have to explode the file for other reason too.

```
if(isset($_GET["title"])){
        $title = $_GET["title"];
        $cri = $_GET["criteria"];
        $err1 = "";
        $err2 = "";
        if(strlen($title) == 0){
            $err1 = "Please Enter Title For Searching";
            echo"<p> ",$err1,"</p>";
            return;
        }
        $file = "../data/jobs.txt";
        if(! file_exists($file)){
            $err2 = "The Job Text File Is not Exist!!!";
            echo"<p> ",$err2,"</p>";
            return;
        }
        if($err1 == "" && $err2 == ""){
            $count = 0;
            $alljobs = file($file);
            for($i = 0;$i < count($alljobs);$i++){
                $collumns = explode("\t",$alljobs[$i]);
                $colTit = explode(":",$collumns[1]);
                $colPos = explode(":",$collumns[4]);
                $colCon = explode(":",$collumns[5]);
                $colApp = explode(":",$collumns[6]);
                $colLoca = explode(":",$collumns[7]);
                $timeValue = explode(":",$collumns[3]);
                echo strtotime($timeValue[1]);
```

Comment: You might want to clarify if the string in your text file is the markup shown in your question with the HTML tags and such, or whether it is just the output rendered in the question. Might be a good idea to pop it into a code box itself.

Comment: Does `$timeValue[1]` actually contain the date you expect? It might be an idea to check.

Comment: any particular reason why you have this ugly `txt` formatting? Why not `json` or `xml` or `csv` to make it easier to parse?

Answer (score 0):

the

```
$timeValue[1]
```

will contain

```
</strong> 25/09/2013
```

you should remove the

```
</strong>
```

String

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$timeValue` does indeed contain the date string from your file, you're going to have trouble using the date format *d/m/Y* with `strtotime()` as it will treat ambiguous dates like `9/3/2013` as *m/d/Y* format.

You should instead use `DateTime::createFromFormat`, for example

```
$closingDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $timeValue[1]);
```

You can then compare this with your server time easily using

```
$diff = $closingDate->diff(new DateTime());
```